# Swift Encodable, Decodable Vs Codable

Tags: swift, composition, codable, decodable, encodable

Found in Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable), that `Codable` protocol is composed of `Encodable` and `Decodable`. Thus,

```
Codable = Encodable & Decodable
```

Now, let's say I implemented below classes,

```
class X: Codable {
    var name: String
}

class Y: Encodable, Decodable {
    var name: String
}

class Z: Encodable & Decodable {
    var name: String
}
```

**So, is there any functional difference among the classes, `X`, `Y` and `Z`?**

If there is no deference why can't we use `&` in the places of `,`?

Comment: i think no difference

Comment: btw y,z are literally the same it's class name change so no comparison

Comment: @Sh_Khan I think the difference is between using `&` and `,` to delimit the protocols. OP is suspecting that it will cause a difference.

Comment: @Sweeper yes i noticed it and will clarify it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No there isn't any difference , `Codable` is a typealias for `Encodable & Decodable` , so it combines the 2 protocols you're free to use any way

> In Swift **&** is the same as **,** in protocol composition so `Encodable, Decodable` = `Encodable & Decodable` = `Codable`

Answer (score 6):

**Encoding**
The process of converting your custom type instances to other representation such as JSON and pList is known as Encoding or Serialization. For encoding, custom types conform to Encodable protocol.

**Decoding**
The process of converting data in representation such as JSON or pList to instance of your custom type is known as Decoding or Deserialization. For decoding, custom types conform to Decodable protocol.

**Codable**
To support both encoding and decoding, custom types can conform to Codable protocol which conforms to both Encodable and Decodable.

to Read more about **Codable**, **Decoding** and **Encoding** [Click on the this Link](https://medium.com/@manojkarkie/encodable-and-decodable-in-swift-4-747328a7c7c5)

Answer (score 4):

They are functionally the same but you can do things with the & syntax that you can't with a comma separated list. Neither of these would work with the comma approach.

```
public typealias Codable = Decodable & Encodable

func doSomething(with item: ProtocolA & ProtocolB) {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't think so. Codable means they can be decoded from and encoded into another representation. Decodable means it can be decoded, but not encoded. And encodable is the opposite of that.